# WPF - Cannot get Bound Data to display in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, observablecollection

I have a list in gridview. I have bound the gridview columns to get set members in a class JFifoData, instances of which I have collected in an Observable Collection. I have then bound the ListView ItemsSource to this collection. For some reason, however, the data is not being displayed when I run the program. Here is the relevant code, am I doing something wrong?

XAML Code

```
<ListView Name="JfifoList" ItemsSource="{Binding JFifoCollection}">>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" Header="time" Width="225"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FEStatus}" Header="fe status" Width="225"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BEStatus}" Header="be status" Width="225"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Trigger}" Header="trigger" Width="350"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

JFifoData class

```
public class JFifoData
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string FEStatus  { get; set; }
    public string BEStatus  { get; set; }
    public string Trigger  { get; set; }

    public uint TID  { get; set; }
    public uint Frames  { get; set; }
    public uint HWCRC  { get; set; }
    public uint FPS  { get; set; }
    public string Faults { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string Config { get; set; }
}
```

get member of my window class

```
public ObservableCollection<JFifo.JFifoData> JFifoCollection
{
    get
    {
        return Fifo.CollectedData;
    }
}
```

Initialization of the Observable Collection

```
Data = new ObservableCollection<JFifoData>();
Data.Add(new JFifoData
{
    Time = new DateTime(),
    FEStatus = "FE Good",
    BEStatus = "BE Good",
    Trigger = "Trigged"
});
Data.Add(new JFifoData
{
    Time = new DateTime(),
    FEStatus = "FE Bad",
    BEStatus = "BE Bad",
    Trigger = "Not Trigged"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, however, if this is all the relevant parts of your code, you have not set the `DataContext` for your `ListView`. Do the following:

```
JfifoList.DataContext = theClassWhichExposesJFifoCollection
```

It would also appear that your XAML is malformed. Look at the first line:

```
<ListView Name="JfifoList" ItemsSource="{Binding JFifoCollection}">>
```

It has two angle-brackets at the end!

Comment: I set the Data Context, now I get this error: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource. I guess that's because I add stuff to it as soon as I initialize it.

Comment: Damn. These little things get so annoying. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `DataContext` isnt set correctly. Run the code and then take a look at Visual Studios output window and see if you get any binding errors.

Comment: DataContext as the problem. Thanks!